# Zeno’s Paradox of the Arrow

Tags: kinematics, velocity

> **Premises And the Conclusion of the Paradox**: (1) When the arrow is in a place just its own size, it’s at rest. (2) At every moment of its flight, the arrow is in a place just its own size. (3) Therefore, at every moment of its flight, the arrow is at rest.

If something is at rest, it certainly has $0$ or no velocity. So, in modern terms, what the paradox says is that the velocity of the arrow in "motion" at any instant $t$ (a duration-less duration) of time is '$0$'.

I read a solution to this logical paradox. I do not remember who proposed it, but the solution was something like this:

> Let the average velocity of the arrow be the ratio $$\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}.$$
>   Where $\Delta s$ is a 'finite' interval of distance, travelled over a finite duration $\Delta t$ of time. Because an instant is duration-less, and no distance is travelled during the instant, therefore $$\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}=\frac{0}{0}$$ or, $$0 \cdot \Delta s=0 \cdot \Delta t.$$
>   In other words, the velocity at an instant is indeterminate, because the equation above has no unique solution.

This solution denies the concept of a 'definite' instantaneous velocity at some instant $t$ given by the limit of the ratio $\frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}$ or $$v(t)= \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}  \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}.$$

Whatever be the velocity at some instant $t$, how does the above "definition of the instantaneous velocity" or the calculus tell us that the arrow or any other object in motion is moving at an instant? How can something move in a duration-less instant, when it has no time to move? What is the standard modern science solution to understand this logical paradox?

Comment: Calculus is the solution. It's not even that modern. Zeno assumes (without saying so) that time is discrete, and observing the world demonstrates that this is pure nonsense.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Zeno++-[quantum-mechanics]

Comment: Is time not discrete?

Comment: There is no sign of discrete time at any energy scale we can probe. Mathematical rules based on continuous time are successful at describing the world.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no such instant as $t$ in time?

Comment: I am using the words "discrete" and "continuous" in there mathematical sense. Zeno talked about time without those concepts and constructed a bunch of mistakes (he presumably knew them to be such) as a consequence of the fuzzy imprecision of everyday language. That imprecision is the *whole* source of the "paradox". Math is the proper language of physics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a finite unit of distance that we cannot divide past?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51652/)

Comment: @dmckee I'm sorry, but can you tell me what the words 'discrete' and 'continuous' mean in their mathematical sense?

Comment: I don't see a paradox. The arrow is at rest in its own frame, but that doesn't mean *that the ground is at rest*. In fact, the ground *is* what is moving according to the arrow.

Comment: @KyleKanos :  And why can't the arrow make the same argument with respect to the ground that we on the ground have made with respect to the arrow?

Comment: @WillO: Remember your (inertial) frame invariance. You can freely swap out "ground" and "arrow" and the relation will *always* hold.

Comment: I, now, think that it is not a physicist's job or of a student studying physics to indulge in such kind of philosophical arguments. All we can believe in is the language of mathematics as it has proved to be fruitful. As far as the question of the motion of the arrow at an instant is concerned, I do not know how to imagine it. However, the arrow has a precise location at every instant given by the function $x(t),$ and some definite velocity as calculus tells us. But, it is very difficult for me to say anything about the arrow's motion, as we perceive it in an interval of time, at an instant.

Comment: @KyleKanos:  Yes, that's the point.  You can freely swap out "ground" and "arrow", and one way or the other,  the paradox survives.

Comment: Look up Heisenberg uncertainty principle and you will find this statement to bed incorrect

Comment: @WillO: There's no paradox because *something* is moving in both frames. Zeno says that the arrow doesn't move because $v=0$ in its own frame *while ignoring the ground is moving in the arrow's frame*.

Comment: Look up Heisenberg uncertainty principle and you will find this statement to be incorrect. Consider this, if you make a photograph of a moving object, with small enough exposure time, the object will be sharp and appears not to be moving, so nothing can be said about the velocity. This is like your limit case. Only way this can be solved is to prolong the exposure time. Now you get a blurry image, from which you can derive the velocity. But your stuck on the position.

Comment: @KvdLingen Isn't the velocity that we derive from the blurry image the average velocity?

Comment: I disagree with Kyle Kanos's view of what Zeno intended to show. As far as I know, Zeno's arrow paradox was intended to show that the arrow cannot move in *our* frame of reference. Zeno wouldn't have referred to "frame of reference" because that concept wasn't isolated until later, but, precisely because the notion of varying the frame of reference wasn't yet under discussion, what Zeno said in "absolute" terms should be understood by us modern folks as being about our frame of reference. In other words, Zeno's paradox is resolved by calculus, not by considering other reference frames.

Comment: @samama Yes.  It is

Comment: But in classical mechanics, velocity and position are completely deterministic, aren't they?

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Zeno of course didn't use the terminology "frame of reference," but that doesn't mean it can't be used to *resolve* the "paradox."

Comment: @samama. Yes they are. That's why classical mechanics has constraints on it use. It is also what the answerer states. The definition of velocity is useless in zero-time.

Comment: @KyleKanos:  For goodness's sake.  Here we have a purported proof that nothing can move in any frame.  You claim to refute this proof by pointing to the fact that the ground is moving in the arrow's frame.  One might just as well refute the proof by pointing to the fact that the arrow is moving in the ground's frame.  The only impact of these observations is to show that Zeno conclusion is wrong. They contribute nothing to pinpointing the error in the Zeno argument.  And in particular, since it has *already been noted* that there is a frame in which something moves, it adds ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd)....absolutely nothing to point out that there is *another* frame in which *something else* moves.  Two counterexamples to the conclusion are no more powerful than one counterexample to the conclusion.

Comment: Please continue further discussion in [chat]. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like all paradoxes, there is no contradiction here, just misuse of logic.

How do you *define* velocity? If you say

> the distance traveled in an extended period of time, divided by that time

well then of course there's no such thing as instantaneous velocity. Asking what something's instantaneous velocity is under this definition is logically equivalent to something like

> Let $n$ be the number of apples in a nonempty container of apples. What is $n$ when the container has no apples?

The question doesn't make sense, and *simply cannot be answered*.

---

Now one can often extend definitions so that terms get defined in new circumstances, consistent with the cases for which they were previously defined. We define velocity as
$$ v = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}. $$
This is consistent with the old in the sense that if you have a constant velocity $v$ and you travel for an extended period of time, $v$ is given by distance divided by time.

But make no mistake, our new definition *goes beyond* cases of extended time intervals, and in these cases the old definition *still fails*, just as it always did. Sure no motion occurs if no time elapses. So what? If no time elapses, the definition of velocity has nothing to do with actual distance traveled over that time.

Some object may have a nonzero velocity because our new definition of velocity says it does, whereas the old definition may have had nothing to say one way or the other. Make no mistake, the old definition does *not* say the velocity of an object is $0$ if no time elapses. It says the velocity of an object is currently *undefined* if no time elapses.

Comment: So, velocity has nothing to do with the question if the object is in motion at some instant or not. Right?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "in motion." The sensible definition says velocity is nonzero if and only if the object is in motion. Zeno's definition of "in motion" isn't defined for a single instant.

Comment: Re: Let n be the number of apples in a nonempty container of apples. What is n when the container has no apples? // Answer: A fat worm.

Answer (score 0):

> How can something move in a duration-less instant, when it has no time
> to move?

According to elementary calculus, if the position of the arrow is given by the function $x(t)$, then

$$x(t + dt) = x(t) + v(t)dt$$

This *defines* the instantaneous velocity:  it is the ratio of the [infinitesimal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Infinitesimal.html)$^\dagger$ change in position to the *infinitesimal* change in time

$$v(t) = \frac{dx}{dt} $$

Contrast this with

$$x(t + 0) = x(t) $$

and note that an *infinitesimal* displacement in space or time is not identical to a zero displacement or "duration-less instant".

$\dagger$ *An infinitesimal is some quantity that is explicitly **nonzero** and yet smaller in absolute value than any real quantity*

Comment: Please see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-dy-dx-not-a-ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Since the definition of Velocity is the *change* in distance traveled divided by the *change* in time elapsed, and since there is *no change* in either distance or time ($dx=0$, $dt=0$), Velocity is simply undefined mathematically at a point.

In practical terms this means of course that there *never* is a instant when the arrow is not moving, so $dx$ is undefined, and so is $dt$ given. The concept of velocity can therefore *not* be defined at an instant, only over a period of time. There is no paradox, and the question itself is incorrectly phrased.

Momentum is of course defined at any time the object is moving, but is 0 when it is at rest. To argue about "instant velocity" is to argue that momentum is 0 at any/every given point in the object's path of motion. This is of course, ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time since this question is asked. But I see many confusion in the answers. In fact it is simple. The aporia proves that the arrow is at rest but of course in its own system. It omits the relativity of motion. An object is always at rest in its own reference system but not in all reference systems. So in a system of Earth (appr. inertial) it is moving.

Answer (score 0):

The paradox is nonsense. When you see a fast exposure photograph of a moving car it seems to be motionless. So Zeno's paradox effectively asks 'if the car was motionless for the instant that the photo was taken, and if time is just a succession of instants in which the car is motionless, then how does the car move? How does a succession of zero movements ad up to a non-zero movement?'

The answer is that the car is not motionless while the photograph is being taken- it moves by an unnoticeable but non-zero amount. If you half the exposure time, you half the distance the car moves, but it still moves. You can keep decreasing the time interval, and the car still moves by a decreasing amount, but the ratio of the distance moved divided by the time interval remains constant. You can take the time duration as close to zero as you like, and the car still moves some distance during the interval.